# Define Markov chain and rewrite to recursively solve

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

> Customers arrive at a server with rate $\lambda$ and are served at rate $\mu$. The server breaks down with rate $\gamma$, which causes all customers to leave. New customers can only arrive once the server has been repaired, which happens at rate $\delta$. Model as a MC give balance equations, and rewrite those so that they can be recursively solved (i.e. express for instance $\pi_k$ in $\pi_{k-n}$ ($n=1,\dots k$), $k=1,2,\dots$. You don't have to solve the equations.

My approach. Let $X(t)$ be the number of customers in the system and let the state space be $A=\{d, 0, 1, \dots\}$ where $d$ denotes a state in which the server is down.

The transition rates are then: $q_{d,0}=\delta$, $q_{i,d}=\gamma$, $q_{i,i+1}=\lambda$, $q_{i,i-1}=\mu$.

Then \begin{align*}\delta \pi_d &= \gamma \quad[\text{is this correct or should it be } \delta \pi_d = \gamma \pi_i, \ i =0,1,\dots?]\\ \lambda \pi_0 &= \mu \pi_1 + \delta \pi_d\\ (\lambda + \mu)\pi_i &= \lambda \pi_{i-1} + \mu \pi_{i+1}, \quad i \geq 2\\ \sum_i \pi_i&=1\end{align*}

Is my definition of the Markov chain correct and are the balance equations correct (specifically the first equation)? Also, how can I then rewrite the system so that it can be recursively solved like the question asks?

Comment: Is there some context to determine what these variables actually mean?  This problem is annoyingly ambiguous.  What does it mean to repair a server at rate $\delta$?  What does it mean to breakdown at rate $\gamma$ ?  Probability of breakdown per customer?  Amount of breakdowns per unit time?  This problem seems to be a guessing game.

Comment: @DanielV I agree with you but I know from experience that when my book writes it like this it means '$\delta$ is the rate at which servers are repaired' and '$\gamma$ is the rate at which servers break down'.

Comment: That would be the context that the rest of us have to guess.  All you did was repeat what the problem wrote, not add clarity.

Comment: @DanielV Well since my book always uses this way of expression I assumed it to be standard. Anyway, if it was unclear to you I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: The statement of the exercise is *not* ambiguous since "rate" has a precise meaning in the context of the theory of Markov processes. But, more annoyingly, the first part of the exercise is to "Model as a MC" and yet we do not see the OP's model. Defining a Markov chain usually involves specifying some transition rates, where are these?

Comment: @Did I thought they just meant that I should define the states and the state space.

Comment: @Did I added them to the OP.

Comment: Please be MUCH more careful: the rates you suggest involve undefined parameters alpha and beta and do not seem to take seriously into account the break down part of the model.

Comment: @did Sorry, for some dumb reason I replaced $\gamma$ and $\delta$ by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in my solution. I apologize a 1000 times, this is very stupid.

Comment: @did I don't exactly get what you mean. I do right? By including the state $d$ (server down)?

Comment: The state $d$ is necessary but your balance equations are odd: to begin with state $d$, one leaves $d$ at rate $\delta$ hence the flux going out of $d$ is $\delta\pi_d$, but one can arrive at $d$ from every other state, right? So the flux coming in $d$ is... Likewise for state $0$.

Comment: @did. So what I put between brackets is then correct? $\delta \pi_d = \gamma \pi_i i = 0,1,\dots$? Also, I don't really get your comment on state $0$, you can only go to state $0$ from state 1 right? Isn't it the case that only 1 person can be served at a time (and that hence the rest form a queue)? (The problem doesn't really mention this, but that's what I thought.)

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand "$\delta \pi_d = \gamma \pi_i, \ i =0,1,\dots$" (that is, unless $\pi_i=\pi_0$ for every $i\ne d$, which we have no reason to assume). // "you can only go to state 0 from state 1 right" No, also from state $d$.

Comment: @did Okay, you're right about the fact that you can go from state $d$ to state $0$, I added that to the equations in the OP now. However, I still don't understand your first comment. Why can the machine *only* break down if there are no customers? It can also break down if there are $1, 2$ or more customers, right? Or do you mean that because the exercise says *which causes all customers to leave* the state becomes zero first from there and then goes into state $d$? In that case I interpreted the question differently

Comment: "Why can the machine only break down if there are no customers?" ?? Did I ever say this? Quite the contrary, I seem to have written that "one can arrive at d from every other state".

Comment: @did Then why did you say that my solution is only correct if $\pi_i=\pi_0$ for $i \neq d$? Can you please tell me what should be the correct equation then?

Comment: More precisely, I brought your attention to the equations $\delta\pi_d=\gamma$ (obviously wrong) and $\delta\pi_d=\gamma\pi_i$ (obviously absurd since one does not know what is $i$) and I suggested to revise them. And I went as far as indicating how. Now, it is up to you to write correct balance equations.

Comment: @Did Yes, so you´re saying that it should be $\delta \pi_d = \gamma \pi_0$ right? So that's why I said, does that then mean that when the server breaks down, first the state becomes $\pi_0$ (system becomes empty) and then $d$?

Comment: No I am not saying that and it is not true because (*bis repetita*, or is it *ter repetita*?) "one can arrive at d from every other state". See, perhaps, perhaps, from now on you should try to concentrate on what the solution should be, rather than (mis)interpreting what I wrote.

Comment: @Did I then really just do not see what it should be. Can you please just tell me?

Comment: Many, too many comments ago, I indicated that one should determine "the flux coming in $d$". We are still stuck at this point because you did nothing of the sort. As already said, "it is up to you".

Comment: @did And I gave you several suggestions to what I thought it would be and according to you none of them are correct so then it doesn't seem weird to me that I'm asking you what it should be. It's not as if I am asking you to solve the whole exercise...

Comment: Nothing prevents you to write the balance equation at state $d$. Just do it.

Comment: @did The only options I can think of are $\delta \pi_d = \gamma \pi_i$ and $\delta \pi_d = \gamma \pi_0$. This is getting repetitive. Please then at least tell me what I should think of.

Comment: @did I really find it a pity that you are not being cooperative in helping me in this tiny step. I really did try but if you then point out that something is wrong then I feel that you should also tell me why this is wrong and what is right.

Comment: @Did Okay, one last try because you insist: $\delta \pi_d = \gamma (1-\pi_d)$. Is that correct?

Comment: "if you then point out that something is wrong then I feel that you should also tell me why this is wrong and what is right." In other words, you want a complete solution [and you want it now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MStoUfrsCig)? Sorry but no.